# Assert operator to count before and after from various variable

Tags: assert, assertion, katalon-studio

i have codes to get database records, send test data (not shown in below codes), 
and count before/after size.

can i do below assertion to do simple math calculation directly using the printIn result?

```
 assert responseListAfter.size() == responseListBefore.size + results
```

this is the full codes

```html
//count the DB records which State = New

String dbQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dispenseorders.dispenseorder where status = 'true'"

List results = CustomKeywords.'swisslog.database.getSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString , GlobalVariable.dbUsername , GlobalVariable.dbPassword ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver ,dbQuery )

println results



//Before Refresh. count number of records in Kafka Topic A
def TopicBefore = 'A'

def NewMessageBefore = consumeMessageBefore(TopicBefore)

def responseListBefore = new JsonSlurper().parseText(consumeMessageBefore.getResponseText())

def consumeMessageBefore(def topic) {
 WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Object Repository/Kafka/subscribe_to_topic_A', [('topic_name') : topic, ('KafkaRestName') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestName
    , ('KafkaRestPort') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestPort]))
 
 return consumeMessageBefore = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject('Object Repository/Kafka/consume_message_from_topic_for_DR',
   [('KafkaRestName') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestName, ('KafkaRestPort') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestPort]))
}


println('before Request Refresh: \n' + responseListBefore.size)


WebUI.delay(10)

//after Refresh. count number of records in Kafka Topic A
def TopicAfter = 'A'

def NewMessageAfter = consumeMessageAfter(TopicAfter)

def responseListAfter = new JsonSlurper().parseText(consumeMessageAfter.getResponseText())

def consumeMessageAfter(def topic) {
 WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Object Repository/Kafka/subscribe_to_topic_for_DR', [('topic_name') : topic, ('KafkaRestName') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestName
    , ('KafkaRestPort') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestPort]))
 
 return consumeMessageAfter = WS.sendRequestAndVerify(findTestObject('Object Repository/Kafka/consume_message_from_topic_for_DR',
   [('KafkaRestName') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestName, ('KafkaRestPort') : GlobalVariable.KafkaRestPort]))
}

println('after Request Refresh: \n' + responseListAfter.size)

//check total messages. After Refresh count = Before Refresh count + DB records
assert responseListAfter.size() == responseListBefore.size + results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is a list, and you need a list size (int) to add it to other ints:

```
assert responseListAfter.size() == responseListBefore.size() + results.size()
```